# How can I locate my static folder in flask with a divisional blueprint?

Tags: python, flask, routes

I've been trying to do a divisional blueprint but I'm having a hard time locating my individual static folders per blueprint. can someone help me see what's missing?

Here's my code in route.py

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template

admin = Blueprint('admin', __name__,
                template_folder="templates",
                static_folder="static")

@admin.route('/admin')
def admin_home():
    return render_template("admin_home.html")
```

here's my directory

```
>website
.   .>admin
.   .  .>static
.   .  .    admin_style.css
.   .  .    index.js
.   .  .>templates
.   .  .__init__.py
.   .  .routes.py
.   .>public
.   .>api
.   .>users
.   .__init__.py
.main.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the 'static_url_path' argument to the blueprint config:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template

admin = Blueprint('admin', __name__,
                template_folder="templates",
                static_folder="static",
                static_url_path="/admin/static")

@admin.route('/admin')
def admin_home():
    return render_template("admin_home.html")
```

Assuming your static directory contains a folder named css with your css files in it, you would then access these static files in your HTML like so:

```
<link href="{{ url_for('.static', filename='css/styles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

The full-stop before the static is important here - without it, the template will try to use the static folder in the application's parent directory. The css/styles.css is simply just the folder followed by the filename you're trying to link to. So this could be img/my_img.png or js/my_js.js

Bit of documentation here if it helps: [Flask - Static Files](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/blueprints/?highlight=static_url_path#static-files)

Comment: thank you sir, I've tried this but still, I'm getting 404 errors for .css and .js in my static, and I've also tried reading and following the documentation link there but still cant find it. i tried looking back and fort for the linking f my CSS to my HTML and its correct, idk whats wrong guess ill just have to stick to functional blueprint

Comment: Updated my answer now - sorry, left the linking part out

Comment: THANK YOU SIR IT WORKED WITH THIS:

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('admin.static', filename='admin_style.css') }}">

THANKS A LOT!!

Comment: No problem at all - glad I could help